# Receiving UDP packets without port forwarding

Tags: networking, router, port-forwarding

I just tested a udp sender/receiver code and I couldn't quite understand port forwarding.

**A** is my PC in a non port forwarded network, and **B** is a UDP server on my vps, which is port forwarded.

- case 1:

A starts listening to udp packets on port **X**. The vps (B) sends packets from port **Y** but A doesnt get them because it is not port forwarded.

- case 2:

But when A sends something to the server (B) and the server responds, I get the response. **Why doesn't this need port forwarding?**

A can be in a LAN with several conected devices. How does the router know that the packet has to be forwarded to A in case 2, but not in case 1?

Comment: "How does the router know that the packet has to be forwarded to A in case 2, but not in case 1?" Because router "remembering" in NAT mapping table that connection(IMO bad wording when it applied to UDP) was initiated from LAN  to B. (In case it isn't draconian corporate firewall/router but retail  of the shelf router).  Router in this case will keep this association between A and B as trusted (since it was initiated form "home", which in my opinion is wrong if router think it is trusted) for a limited time and if A won't send anything to B then "sesame" gate will be closed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> A can be in a LAN with several connected devices. How does the router know that the packet has to be forwarded to A in case 2, but not in case 1?

Because routers, firewalls and devices which use [NAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation)(network address translation) have a NAT table which keeps track of incoming packets that will be NAT'ed and sent out to their destination.

The NAT table includes a source device IP address, Port number and Protocol(TCP/UDP). So when **A** does send a packet to **B**(vps), the NAT device adds a record to the NAT table, so that when the packet is returned from **B**, it reads the destination IP, Port, and Protocol, and tries to find a match in the NAT table, and NATs the response back to server **A**.

> A starts listening to udp packets on port X. The vps (B) sends packets from port Y but A doesn't get them because it is not port forwarded.

Server **A** will not get the packet, because it will be dropped by your router. Since there is no port forwarding, and the NAT table does not include a record that matches the destination IP, Port and Protocol.

When you have a device behind a firewall or router, and you are using NAT, you need to use port forwarding so that the router knows that the packet sent from **B** which includes the destination IP address, Port number, and protocol of server **A**, need to be forwarded to server **A**, and not dropped.

I Hope that I answered your question.

Comment: I think that phrase "which keep track of incoming packets that will be NATed" should be "which keep track of outgoing packets that will be NATed" would "sounds" better since if incoming packets isn't related to LAN and aren't forwarded then NAT shouldn't worry about incoming packets

Answer (score 0):

**A** start a conversation with **B**. But **B** cannot start a conversation with **A**.

Once **A** has started a conversation with **B**, **B** can respond to that conversation. But he still cannot start one with **A**.

**little more technical**

With **A** you are starting a UDP socket. Once that UDP socket has started, **A** can send packages to **B** and **B** can respond to it by writing the response to the socket. **A** then reads the response.
**B** cannot talk to **A** because **A** is not allowing it to start socket with them.

How does he know its you? Well **B** does not know who you are. The router just tracks the socket association which leads to **A**.

Its alot like when you browse trough the web. You are the one downloading the files and viewing them. You are opening a connection trough wich you download the files. And not the other way around. The webserver is just responding to your requests.

Comment: Association is probably a better term. UDP doesn't have connections after all. It's time-limited, too.

Comment: Could you explain? Because in C# we are starting an UDP socket connection in which we send packages constantly. So I'm not sure what you mean by Association.

Comment: Just read the [Wikipedia article on UDP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Datagram_Protocol). That’s just the wrong vocabulary. You’re opening a *[socket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_socket)*. Because you want to receive responses, a NAT router has to track that *association*.

Comment: @DanielB : Though I appreciate your attempt to improve accuracy, I'm not sure that's right. e.g., [OpenBDD PF Filter info about UDP state](https://www.openbsd.org/faq/pf/filter.html#udpstate) speaks similar: "UDP is a stateless protocol", yet the product's docs (right there) say how UDP states are used anyway.  Despite UDP widely taught as a Connectionless protocol, a firewall(/router?) could still track UDP based on time, and implement what it might call a "connection".  Wikipedia's UDP article doesn't contain "association", which is usually used to refer to a (Wi-Fi) Layer 2 connection.

Comment: @TOOGAM The page you linked to calls it "session". IPTables simply calls it "established". Whatever you call it, it's not a connection. The state only exists on routers that decide to track connections. It does not exist on either conversation participant. /edit: Another good example is ICMP. It's also stateless yet you want to receive echo replies and whatnot.